# Form cannot pass value in php

Tags: php

I want to pass the $username value to doMember.php page from member.php with form :

member :

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
<form name="member" method="get" action="doMember.php?user=<?php echo $username;?>">
```

in the doMember.php page :

```
$username = $_GET["user"];
echo $username;
```

but the $username in doMember.php is empty. Is there something missing?

Comment: do you have <? and ?> around the `$username = $_GET['user']` in the first part of the code?

Comment: can you echo the value of this $username in member.php

Comment: Is there more to the form than what you have in the example?

Comment: In `member.php` you're trying to put the `$_GET['user']` value in `$username` before submitting the `$_GET` request.

Comment: yes I do have <??> around the $username and the php tag already enclosed before the form starts. I am sorry for the incompleteness

Answer (score 3):

HTML and PHP are not the same

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
echo '<form name="member" method="get" action="doMember.php?user='.$username.'">';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not set the parameters in the action. Take a look at the generated HTML, you'll see your form will be sent to `"doMember.php?user="`, so you'll always send an empty user.

The browser will append all form variables to the `action` upon submit, so simply put `doMember.php`.

Comment: Hypothetically, I agree. But the OP's approach should work, assuming there isn't another issue with the form.

Answer (score 2):

You should place the username in an

```
<input type="hidden" name ="username" val="usr">
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Form method='post'

The field name of that form must be named "user"

Answer (score 1):

Can't you include the value of $user_name in a hidden variable in your  so
    $username = $_GET['user'];

```
    <form name="member" method="get" action="doMember.php">
      <input type="hidden" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"
      .
      .
      . 
    </form>
```

Comment: Can anyone let me know how to post HTML in an answer? I had to replace < and > tags by their corresponding entities. and add a <pre> tag. Sorry, still a newbie here :-)